# If you mean 'good' then say so!

Tags: british-english

Why do the British, myself included, ofttimes respond to an inquiry which could be answered by "Good" or "Fine" by saying "Not bad" or "Not bad at all"?

Comment: If you do it yourself then you already know the answer.

Comment: Well, perhaps it's not "Fantastic!"

Comment: Can you add a few examples of such exchanges?